# Zoom UIView without using UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, zooming

How can i zoom a UIView without using UIScrollBar? I can add pinch gesture recognizer but how can i move the zoomed image to selected area?

Answer (score 0):

What prevents you from using UIScrollView? It is probably the most easy way to handle zooming and scrolling.

If UIScrollView is not allowed. You can probably add pinch and pan gesture recognizer and implement their delegates for zooming and scrolling.

Comment: OK this is very basic question. If i want to zoom a uiview do i have to add this view as subview to uiscrollview or i can add this uiview as a subview to the Viewcontroller holding uiscrollview?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this..

[Image-manipulation-with-uigesturerecognizer](http://rogchap.com/2011/06/10/ios-image-manipulation-with-uigesturerecognizer-scale-move-rotate/)

[Here is Sample Project](https://github.com/rogchap/SampleProjects)